# Play store signin failed

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

When I release the app to play store, signin to play store is failed. It shows an error. The error is 
*You have imported an APK or Android App Bundle with a signature in debug mode. You must sign it in output version mode. Learn more about the signature.*
I have used the key to build.gradle. I set the properties to the key.properties.
key.properties is like this:

```
storePassword=*******
keyPassword=*********
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/home/user/key.jks
```

And the build.gradle is like this

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Inside the android{} I added like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

I generated the key by this command.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

But still it's showing an error. It's not signing to play store.

Comment: try updating the version of your code

Comment: Okay. But our app version is 1.0. So, versionCode must be 1 right?

Comment: saret suggestion looks right try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
change this:

release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
```

with that:

```
release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```